# Code to control monitors and their background color problem

Tags: windows

I don't know hot to get started. I recognized this is not a coding site, but considering that EE are close related to software development , I will shoot my question here.

I am looking for a code that will signal the user information of multiple monitors attached to the User computer. Then what follows is to allow user control the screen background color.For example, to set a particular monitor to FULL SCREEN BLUE or any other color of choice. A similar example is found in http://lcdtech.info/en/tests/dead.pixel.htm

Feel free to point me to any other forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an EE question and because code requests are categorically off topic in almost all of the stack exchange network.

Comment: There are approved tags very relevant to my question (Windows, Software, Softcore) Why will the tags be listed if there is no room for software questions within this exchange?

Comment: Those tags are only to give *context* to on-topic questions, asking questions *about* them is off topic (with the exception of `softcore`, which doesn't mean what you seem to think it does - it is about processors built in the fabric of an FPGA).  Additionally, even somewhere else in the SE system where the topic matter might be on-topic, code request questions are still off topic as a category.